# How to convert Well Wilders MA to v4?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

```
wwma(l,p) =>

wwma = (nz(wwma[1]) * (l - 1) + p) / l
```

I'm going to convert it to v4, but I got a error,
Undeclared identifier 'wwma'. Then changed to:

```
wwma = 0.

wwma := (nz(wwma[1]) * (l - 1) + p) / l
```

Still an error:

```
Undeclared identifier 'l';
Undeclared identifier 'p';
'wwma' is not a function.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a function `f_wwma` with `l` and `p` arguments as shown below:

```
f_wwma(l, p) =>
    wwma = 0.
    wwma := (nz(wwma[1]) * (l - 1) + p) / l
```

Then you can call that function with defined length (`l`) and source (`p`) arguments:

```
wwma = f_wwma(50, close)

plot(wwma)
```